# Android RelativeLayout and childs with layout_width="match_parent"

Tags: android, width, match, parent, android-relativelayout

How Android calculates the size of a View when I have two Views at the same "row", one with width="fill_parent"?

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"  
        android:hint="Enter some text..."  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>  
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Button01"  
        android:text="Press Here!"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

This code gives all free space to EditText and show the button to his right. But with this changes the EditText fills all width and the button is out of the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"  
        android:hint="Enter some text..."  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>  
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Button01"  
        android:text="Press Here!"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>  
</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"` will force the right bound of the `EditText` to align to the left side of the `Button` , thus Android ignores the `match_parent` width forcing the width to only fill from the left parent side to the right side of the button.

`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText01"` will force the left bound of the `Button` to align to the right side of the `EditText`, but since the `EditText` is `match_parent` width the rights side is aligned to the right side of the parent view and Android will just force the button off the screen.

Comment: In the future you could come back and upvote :) and you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples, `<EditText/>` fits all the width of screen. In the first example, the `Button` is not dependent on `<EditText/>` , so it can align to right edge of screen. In the second example, however, `Button` has to align to the right of `, that's why it gets pushed out of view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `RelativeLayout` then you have no "rows", all you have is a space where you can arrange the views. If you want to keep the button in the right part of the screen and have the EditText fill the rest of the screen you could do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"  
        android:hint="Enter some text..."  
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>  
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Button01"  
        android:text="Press Here!" 
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>  
</RelativeLayout/>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that RelativeLayout doesn't have rows; this was the reason for the quotes. I wanted to know how match_parent works, not a concrete solution. Thanks